# Merge multiple records in the same table in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hello I am dealing with some unfriendly import files which import as:

```
timestamp  position        name
001            2            Jon
001            3            Bob
001            1            Ann
001            4            Mike
002            1            Joe
002            2            Sue
003            1            Jeff
004            5            James
004            1            Andy
004            2            Beth
004            4            Mitch
004            3            Chris
```

And would like to create a new table that displays thusly:

```
timestamp  position1    position2    position3    position4     position5
001           Ann          Jon          Bob          Mike
002           Joe          Sue
003           Jeff
004           Andy         Beth         Chris        Mitch        James
```

By browsing this forum the closest I have come to a solution is:

```
SELECT pos1.timestamp, pos1.name AS position1, pos2.name AS position2
FROM table1 AS pos1 INNER JOIN table1 AS pos2 
ON pos1.timestamp = pos2.timestamp
WHERE (((pos1.position)=1) AND ((pos2.position)=2))
```

I cannot figure out how to expand this to my specs, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the resulkt you wanted in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
TRANSFORM First(Table.[name]) AS FirstOfname
SELECT Table.[timestamp]
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Table.[timestamp]
PIVOT Table.[position];
```

I created this using the MS Access Cross Tab Query Wizard.

Also have a look at

[What is a CrossTab Query?](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=25)

Some better explenation.

- Click the Create tab.
- Click the Query Wizard.
- Select Second Option (Crosstab Query
  Wizard) and hit OK.
- Select the table for your input, and
  hit next.
- Select Timestamp and click the arrow
  (single) pointing fromleft to right,
  and hit next.
- Select position and hit next.
- name will be the remaining field,
  Select First (default is count), and
  hit next.
- Hit finish.

It should have saved a query called Table_Crosstab (or something similar).
Right click this and select design view.
On the view button, select Sql View.

You should see something similar to

```
TRANSFORM First(Table.name) AS FirstOfname
SELECT Table.timestamp, First(Table.name) AS [Total Of name]
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Table.timestamp
PIVOT Table.position;
```

From the second line remove

```
, First(Table.name) AS [Total Of name]
```

so that you end up with

```
TRANSFORM First(Table.name) AS FirstOfname
SELECT Table.timestamp
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY Table.timestamp
PIVOT Table.position;
```

And that should be it. Save and you are ready.

Comment: I don't understand generalities (having started on access today).
Can you be specific as to my particular situation and what I need to do the get the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: OK, i added some steps. Ask if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Your new table is a bad design.  What happens when there is a sixth and a seventh person in the incoming data?   It will also be difficult to work with when you need to pull out all the data by a specific person as you will then need to query five columns.